# How to fill shapes with Texture in a SpriteKit Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, sktexture

I have a texture which looks likes -> 
[image]

Now I want to create a Sprite which looks like

[image]

How would I go about doing this in Sprite Kit project?

Comment: A **single** sprite which is composed of four transformed sprites?

Comment: Skewing is not supported directly in SpriteKit - You may have to split the sprite into 4 smaller sprites, and assign smaller textures to them (there is a initializer for SKTexture that takes as input a base texture and a crop rectangle region) - to skew the sprite you may need to use a custom shader that will skew the texture content.

Comment: spritekit isnt real good at this kinda thing unfortunately =/  you have to find workarounds to accomplish this kind of effect..

Comment: Would it be possible to create a sprite with a `CGPath` that is the outline of what you want, and then set the texture?  I'm not sure if that will crop it to the `CGPath` "outline" though.

Comment: When In was playing with OpenGL, I was able to draw this very easily. First get the texture from the image above(first one). Then set the texture's Wrapping parameter  to GL_REPEAT.  And then setting the glVertexAttribPointer of vertex and associated texture coordinates in the draw call.  However, I want to use the feature SpriteKit provides via the node hierarchy (mainly physics). Since Sprite Kit is written on top of OpenGL-ES, I thought this could be possible by overriding or extending some methods in SKSpriteNode class. :(

Comment: Sprite composition with  Texture splicing will not give the warp/skew effect I am after. :(